# How do I add custom CSS to Slick Slider slide

Tags: css, slider, slick.js

I have searched and researched with no results.

I would like to add some custom CSS to a Slick Slider slide but have not been able to find the correct selector to do so.

For example, on the third slide, I would like to apply some custom CSS; what would be the CSS selector required to do so.

TIA

Lyle

Comment: Could you share an example of the CSS you've tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `:nth-child()` selector and do something like this :

```css
.slick-slide {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slick-slide"></div>
  <div class="slick-slide"></div>
  <div class="slick-slide"></div>
  <div class="slick-slide"></div>
  <div class="slick-slide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much j-printemps, you got me going in the right direction.

This works perfectly to target the third slide (for those using the Elementor Pro Slides widget):

.slick-slide:nth-child(4) .elementor-slide-content {
  color: red;
}